# SqlAlchemy attribute that tracks an assigned attribute

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Goal: Create an SQLAlchemy attribute which tracks/follows changes in another object's SQLAlchemy attribute.

Given:

```
class ClazzA():
    attributeA = Column(JSONDict)

class ClazzB():
    attributeB = Column(?)

objectA = ClazzA()
objectA.attributeA = {'foo': 1}
objectB = ClazzB()
objectB.attributeB = objectA.attributeA
objectA.attributeA['foo'] = 2
```

`JSONDict` is associated with `MutableDict` as described here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/mutable.html#module-sqlalchemy.ext.mutable , i.e. the `JSONDict` type allows for mutation tracking.

So we have this dictionary on objectA whose changes are being recorded by SQLAlchemy. I would like for attributeB to track attributeA such that even if the application is restarted (i.e. the attributes are reloaded from the DB), then attributeB will *continue* to reflect changes made to attributeA's dictionary.

Of course, this is closely related to the fact that Python [doesn't have an idea of pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106689/pointers-in-python). I was wondering if SQLAlchemy has a solution for this particular problem.

Comment: Is `ClazzB` another model? Do you need to persist that model?

Comment: @univerio Yes, ClazzB needs to be persisted as well.

Comment: Do your models `ClazzA` and `ClazzB` have any clear relation at DB level? In other words, if we just get an event like "ClazzA.attributeA was changed for this instance", is there a way to say "This ClazzA instance is related to that ClazzB instance"?

Comment: @Ilja That would be part of the solution. During `__init__` of a `objectB` (or later) we would point it to the intended/paired/matching property on objectA. `attributeB` would only ever point to an `attributeA` on an object of type `ClazzA`, it's just that we don't know which `objectA` until runtime.

Comment: @ChaimKut it sounds a lot like what you're looking for is a ForeignKey + a property on ClazzB.

Comment: Which means we'd need to see a bit more about the real models and what you've tried to do up till now.

Comment: @ChaimKut do you have an existing column in your DB in the table modeled by `ClazzB` that should reflect the column in `ClazzA`? I can see little reason to try and do what you describe otherwise, since it would be against [normalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: @Ilja You can imagine that attributeA is a dictionary of Widgets, and for objectB I am using attributeB to express which Widget I want to be associated with objectB. But if that attributeA Widget described in the dictionary is modified, I want attributeB to reflect that most updated value.

Comment: @ChaimKut hmm, so attributeA of ClazzA holds different widgets in a single JSON structure to which ClazzB should refer to, but do you mean that ClazzB should access values under certain key in that JSON?

Comment: Btw I still think that this model abuses relational model. Instead of storing all widgets in a single row's JSON column create a table *widget* with JSON column and refer to that from ClazzB. Update a row and all ClazzB's have the updates...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## TL;DR

You want a [one-to-many](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many) relationship.

```py
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey, Integer, Column
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship


class Widget(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'widget'

    widget_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    # name columns, type columns, ...
    json = Column(JSONDict)


class ClazzB(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'clazzb'

    clazzb_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    # Your "attributeB"
    widget_id = Column(Integer,
                       ForeignKey('widget.widget_id',
                                  onupdate='cascade',
                                  ondelete='cascade'),
                       nullable=False)

    widget = relationship('Widget')
    # possible association_proxy
    #widget_json = association_proxy('widget', 'json')
```

## Using a Relationship

Define a [relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationships.html) between models `ClazzA` and `ClazzB`. Now since we don't have the whole picture, the below definitions are just examples.

```py
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship


class ClazzA(Base):  # replace Base with the base class of your models

    __tablename__ = 'clazza'  # replace with the real tablename

    # T is the type of your primary key, the column name is just an example
    clazza_id = Column(T, primary_key=True)


class ClazzB(Base):

    # The column that will relate this model to ClazzA
    clazza_id = Column(T, ForeignKey('clazza.clazza_id',
                                     onupdate='cascade',
                                     ondelete='cascade'),
                       nullable=False)

    # A handy accessor for relationship between mapped classes,
    # not strictly required. Configurable to be either very lazy
    # (loaded if accessed by issuing a SELECT) or eager (JOINed
    # when loading objectB for example)
    objectA = relationship('ClazzA')
```

Now instead of adding a reference to `attributeA` of `ClazzA` to `ClazzB` add a reference to related `objectA` to `objectB` on initialization.

```py
objectB = ClazzB(..., objectA=objectA)
```

The two are now related and to access `attributeA` of related `objectA` through `objectB` do

```py
objectB.objectA.attributeA
```

No need to track changes to `attributeA`, since it is the `attributeA` of the instance.

Now if you must have an attribute `attributeB` on `ClazzB` (to avoid refactoring existing code or some such), you could add a property

```py
class ClazzB:

    @property
    def attributeB(self):
        return self.objectA.attributeA
```

which will return the `attributeA` of the related `objectA` with

```py
objectB.attributeB
objectB.attributeB['something'] = 'else'
```

and so on.

There is also an SQLAlchemy method for accessing attributes across relationships: [association proxy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html). It supports simple querying, but is not for example subscriptable.

```py
class ClazzB(Base):

    attributeB = association_proxy('objectA', 'attributeA')
```

If you wish for `ClazzB.attributeB` to access values from the `JSONDict` under certain key, you can for example use something like this

```py
class ClazzB(Base):

    key = Column(Unicode)

    @property
    def attributeB(self):
        return self.objectA.attributeA[self.key]
```

You can also make `attributeB` work as an SQL expression on class level using [hybrid properties](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html), if you need such a thing. You would have to write your class level expressions yourself though.