# How do I change a variable inside a variable?

Tags: python

Here's my code :

```
hp1 = 100
health1 = 'you have', hp1

hp1 = hp1 - 50
health1

print hp1
print health1
```

This is what it prints :

```
50
('you have', 100)
```

Why doesn't the hp1 change inside the health?

Comment: Why do you expect it to change?

Comment: because i subtracted 50 from hp1. I'm new to python so I don't reallly know what i'm doing haha

Comment: Recommended reading: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: You evaluated `hp1` at the point where you assigned it to `health1`.  After that they had no connection.  You're not thinking this through.  Suppose you had instead used `5 + hp1**2/(1 - hp1)`.  Would you still expect the value to track?  Did you think you were creating a closure, and that the expression was reevaluated each time `health1` was referenced?  Clearly not.

Comment: @TomKarzes Not true, at that point there still is a connection: `health1[1] is hp1`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann No.  `health[1]` is `100`, not a reference to `hp1` as you suggest.  They have the same value at that point, but that is *not* a connection.  A connection implies a persistent, bound relationship.  There is none.

Comment: @TomKarzes I didn't say it's a reference to the `hp1` variable, if that's what you mean. But it **is** a reference to the same object that `hp1` references. If `hp1` for example were a list and you appended to it, then that change **would** affect `health1`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Yes, it's true that `health[1] is hp1` is `True` at that point.  But that's not what I meant.  I meant that changing either has no effect on the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you wish to do, you must use a **class**. This is the closest form of a pointer you will encounter in python.

Here is an example :

```
class Health():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.hp = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'You have {}.'.format(self.hp)

health = Health(100)
hp_clone = health
health.hp -= 50

print hp_clone
# Program outputs : You have 50.
```

Your question is also a possible duplicate of
[Pointers in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106689/pointers-in-python) .

What is happening here in your program has been explained by the others.

Answer (score 2):

The following line:

```
health1 = 'you have', hp1
```

Is creating a `tuple` with two values: `"you have"` and `100` (Note that the value of `hp1` is ***copied***, and not ***referenced***). It's then assigning this `tuple` to a new variable named `health1`.

`health1` has nothing to do with `hp1`. If `hp1` get overriden, deleted, thrown away, or anything happens to it, `health1` doesn't care.

---

If you are so eager to pass this variable a reference, you can create a wrapper class around the `int` type:

```
class IntWrapper(object):
     def __init__(self, value):
          self.value = value
     def __add__(self, value):
          return IntWrapper(self.value + value)
     def __iadd__(self, value):
          self.value += value
          return self
     def __sub__(self, value):
          return IntWrapper(self.value - value)
     def __isub__(self, value):
          self.value -= value
          return self
     def __str__(self):
          return str(self.value)
     def __repr__(self):
          return str(self)

hp1 = IntWrapper(100)
health1 = 'you have', hp1

hp1 -= 50

print hp1          # 50
print health1      # ('you have', 50)
```

Comment: If "the value is copied, not referenced", then why is `health1[1] is hp1` true?

Comment: Terminology nitpick: there are no primitive types in Python. `int` objects are full objects, just like any other.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Check out http://pythonvisually.com/ebook/primitive-data-types.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type

Comment: @StefanPochmann I agree. However, if it don't change the internal value then it will not accomplish what OP wants, because `hp1` would point to a new reference, and `health1` would be pointing to a stale one.

Comment: @MatiasCicero Yes, but you'd better not do that with `__sub__`. Do that with `__isub__` instead. Or maybe better with `decrease` or so, calling it as `hp1.decrease(50)` without assignment notation.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Good point. Wasn't aware of that distinction. I updated the code

Comment: Code looks alright now. You're still saying "value copied, not referenced", though.

Comment: @StefanPochmann That's because `int` values are immutable and never allocated dynamically (unless it's a big value, I suppose), i.e. `hp1 is 100` will yield true. If you were to have another variable `hp2 = 100`, then `hp1 is hp2` would also yield `true`. Maybe saying *"values are copied"* is more than confusing enough. I'll try to come up with something better.

Comment: What do you mean with "never allocated dynamically"? That sounds wrong. And based on your understanding, what do you think this prints? `hp1 = 100 + 200; hp2 = 300; print(hp1 is hp2)`

Comment: @MatiasCicero that is simply wrong. `int` objects are like any other object in Python. There is a CPython *implementation detail* that small-ints are cached, but that only works for int values `-5` to `256`, but for any other `int` in Cpython, `x = 400; y =400; print(y is x)` will print `False`. Regardless, you should never rely on the behavior that `some_int is some_other_int` just because `some_int == some_other_int`. This is the point I was getting at that there are no primitive types in Python, and `int` objects are full-fledged objects. note `import sys; print(sys.getsizeof(some_int))`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Where did you run `x = 400; y =400; print(y is x)` and get `False`? It gives me `True` everywhere.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I was running it in an 3.6 interactive interpreter session. If you put both statements on one line, the compiler will be smart enough to make both objects the same, but if you do two separate lines, `>>> x = 400` then `>>> y = 400` then try `x is y` it is showing false on my machine.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah, that's why I used `hp1 = 100 + 200` in my above example.

Comment: @StefanPochmann yes, that probably demonstrates it better than trying to fool the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

To automatically change the output with any mutations of `hp1`, you can use a class:

```
class Health:
   def __init__(self, health):
       self.health = health
   def __add__(self, val):
       return Health(self.health + val)
   def __sub__(self, val):
       return Health(self.health - val)
   def __repr__(self):
       return "you have {}".format(self.health)

hp1 = Health(100)
hp1 -= 50
print(hp1)
```

Output:

```
you have 50
```

Comment: This is the first answer that addresses the *intent* of the question, rather than just explaining the observed results.

Comment: @chepner Well, to be fair, the OP explicitly asked *"Why doesn't the hp1 change inside the health?*", and not *"How to...?"*

Comment: To be fair, in your example, you could have done `a = 0 ; a += 50 ; print a`. I believe you should have written what I answered to be in the OP's scope.

Comment: Uh... what is this? That does **not** do the desired thing.

Answer (score 0):

Because you defined `health1` - a `(string, int)` tuple - as `hp1` was still 100 and didn't change it since then. This is not a pointer in C/C++ sense, just a copy by value.

Comment: what's the solution though?

Comment: Solution to what? Change the variable if you want it to change. Don't change them otherwise. I don't see a problem. Work through a tutorial to get a feeling for how these things work: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Comment: There was no copy by value. Assignment in Python *never copies*

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have done like this,

```
hp1 = 100 # setting hp1 as 100
health1 = 'you have', hp1 # making a tuple 

hp1 = hp1 - 50 # subracting 50 from hp1 -> gives 50 as result
health1 # simply calling health1

print hp1 # displaying hp1
print health1 # displaying health1
```

In this code,

You defined `hp1` as `100`, let it be stored in a location `1000`

You made a tuple names `health1` as `'you have', hp1`. It will be stored in a location say `2000`

You subtracted 50 from `hp1` making `hp1` 50, this will make no change to `health1` variable because it is stored in different location. But it will change the value of `hp1`

Hope this helps.!!