# How to make my Class' objects copied when called upon (when iterated for example)

Tags: python, immutability

I need my class to create new copy of object when referenced.

For example:

```
obj1 = MyClass(1,2)
obj2 = obj1
obj2.1st_att = 5

>>> print obj1
(5,2)
```

I want obj1 to remain unlinked to obj2

Comment: Are you asking how to automatically make a copy of an object every time it is referenced?  That's not at all how Float or Int work.

Comment: duplicate of duplicate : [See my answer on this thread, that also points to another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47871806/how-do-i-change-a-variable-inside-a-variable/47872098#47872098)

Comment: @ScottHunter So how do they work? I want my objects to be immutable basically, so that when iterated upon or referenced any changes made to new object isn't linked to original

Comment: @Rocobop What do you want exactly ? Please write your input, the code you've eventually tried, and the expected output.

Comment: @ScottHunter Its too long to post, but this is the jist of it: I made a list of objects from my class, and I iterated on the list and added each item to a dictionary. the key is the first attribute from my class. Now - the items in the dictionary are linked to the ones in the list. This is *Not* what i want, I need them to be unlinked. In the code I posted the same behavior is demonstrated, I wish to change this.

Comment: Maybe not post the whole code but a snippet that will help understand. You could post a bit portion of code with like 2 objects, the dictionnary in which you tried, the output you are getting that is not right, and the expected output. :) it should be mandatory to provide a [Minimal, complete and Verifiable Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You should [copy](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/copy.html) object in cases like this.

```
from copy import copy
obj1 = MyClass(1,2)
obj2 = copy(obj1)
obj2.1st_att = 5
```

Or deepcopy if your class is complicated and has lots of references.

Comment: I am trying to avoid using copy, but I want that exact behavior to be automatic in my class

Comment: @Rocobop I believe this solution is the one you are looking for.

Comment: Is there suppose to be a link?

Answer (score 0):

Python isn't making a copy of ints or floats every time you assign them to a different variable. The thing is that they're not mutable; there's nothing you could do to an `int` that would change it, so however many variables you assign it to, you won't ever get any surprising behaviour.

With `obj2.1st_att = 5`, you're explicitly modifying an attribute of an object. There's no analog operation to that for an `int`. It is expected that this operation modifies the object, and that this change will be visible to anyone else who holds a reference to that object.

You should not try to work around that behaviour in any way, as that would break a lot of expectations and cause bugs or surprising behaviour in itself. It is good that making a copy of an object is an explicit action you need to take. Get used to it.

Comment: I know... you are getting me wrong - I want every instance of my class to be a copy. Or in essence I want my class's objects to be immutable

Comment: but the only answers I found were on how to block changes made to attributes and that doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Well, do you want to be able to assign to `obj2.1st_att = 5`? Is that an operation the object should support? Or do you merely want to raise an error when anyone tries to assign anything to your object? That's a different discussion than automatically making a copy.

Comment: I just want it to automatically make a new copy when object is referenced, I dont want to block changes to attributes

Comment: So you do not want immutable objects then, okay. Then read my answer again, you also *do not want* automagic copying behaviour. No you don't. You might think that you do, but you don't. Nu-uh. Seriously. [Let it go.](https://media.tenor.com/images/c75bedf16959bc8576f8ead56d94d863/raw)

Comment: But I want changes made to obj2 made only to obj2. Lets put it another way, I want the *entire* object copied, only when the *entire* object is referenced to.

Comment: No, what you want is to explicitly make a `copy` of the object when you want to make a copy of the object. Believe me, you do not want Python to guess what you want it to do. Right now you have encountered one situation where you want a copy. Then make that copy. This does not mean that you will want a copy in every single other situation henceforth. Sometimes you do want the reference, sometimes you don't.

Comment: Listen, I dont want to use copy every time, I want a copy made when I reference the object. can you just please tell me how to accomplish this if you know?

Comment: You can't. You shouldn't. You should really not approach the problem this way. [That's not how this works.](https://imgur.com/qGhiEIe)