# Omitting repetition in long statements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a quite long statement:

```
if LongClassName.results[variable1][longerVariable2][variable3] == 0:
   LongClassName.results[variable1][longerVariable2][variable3] = 42
```

As one can clearly see, there is quite a lot of repetition in this code (the same expression is used in the conditional and in its body). Is there a way of simplifying it? In C++ I could use references, like this:

```
auto &ref = LongClassName.results[variable1][longerVariable2][variable3];
if (ref == 0) {
    ref = 42;
}
```

What is the Pythonic way of simplifying this expression?

Comment: declaring, referencing, and setting a variable is (mostly) language agnostic > https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/python-variables

Comment: @Robin (and @RandomUs1r): Python doesn't have references, so the `ref = 42` wouldn't work with what you're suggesting.

Comment: As stated [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3106752/10484131) it's the Pythonic way to be explicit.

Comment: @martineau - sorry, yeah, you're right. I hadn't noticed that an actual assignment was going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stop and grab the reference a level above this:

```
partial_ref = LongClassName.results[variable1][longerVariable2]
if partial_ref[variable3] == 0:
   partial_ref[variable3] = 42
```

That's not particularly Pythonic, but it's the closest to your original `C++` code.

Answer (score 2):

You could shorten it to some degree like this:

```
container = LongClassName.results[variable1][longerVariable2]
if container[variable3] == 0:
   container[variable3] = 42
```

Python doesn't have totally general references like C++ does, so this creates a shorter name for the container of `variable3` and uses its name in subsequent statements.

Answer (score -1):

```
x = LongClassName.results[variable1][longerVariable2]
if x[variable3] == 0:
   x[variable3] = 42
```

that works but doesn't seem very elegant.

Comment: @jasonharper: Poster changed they're answer since you posted your comment—so it's now like the others and will actually work.