# How to define a variable in Python that points to or is a reference to a list member

Tags: python, list, pointers, reference

I have a Python list, `r[]`, and would like to define references, or aliases to specific members of the list.  This is easy to do in languages with pointers (like C or C++), but I don't see how to do this in Python.

Specifically, I'd like do something like this:

```
r[0] = 1

ac <=addressof> r[0]

ac = 2
```

Now if I evaluate `r[0]` I need it to be 2

Is there a way to define such a reference in Python?

Comment: Hi, did you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106689/pointers-in-python ?