# Can i modify variable in function without return in python like using pointers in c++

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables

i just wanna make learn how can i write this c++ code in python ?

```
#include <iostream>

void modify(int* a){
    *a = 20;
}

int main(){

    int x = 10;
    modify(&x);
    std::cout << x;
    // OUTPUT: 20
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can imitate that by putting the integer to be mutated in a list, but it's not idiomatic.

Comment: Python doesn't Have Pointers

Comment: i know python doesnt have but cant i make a function like this in python

Comment: Is this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/986145/9814037 ? Pretty decent answer from the owner.

Comment: Furthermore, About pointer here is a theory: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3106752/9814037

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is "you can't".  But, if you had a use case where equivalent behaviour was required, the easiest way would be to wrap your variable into a mutable type.  I would do the following:

```py
def modify(a):
    a[0] = 20

x = [10]
modify(x)
print(x[0])
```

Comment: yes this works but i didnt understand why works. Shouldnt be a local variable in function?

Comment: @cacarekt `a` indicates the _list_, not the _contents_ of the list.  So when we say `a[0] = 20` we're changing the _contents_ of the list, but the list itself is unaffected.  Specifically, `a` is a reference to the start of the list.  We haven't changed where it starts, only what comes after.

Comment: Abusing a list for this will be incredibly bad for performance. This isnt C, lists arent fixed size and compiled away. Use a class instead

Comment: @DownloadPizza there was no indication of performance being a concern.  This is simpler, a class is faster, which is better is entirely context dependent.

Answer (score 1):

This can not work for integers because integers in python are completely immutable. You can not change an integer in python.
When you do for example a += 1, you create a new int with the value a + 1 and bind the variable a to it.
Now, the easiest way to do this would be to have some reference type, like a class.

```
class IntRef:
  def __init__(self, a):
    self.a = a

def modify(some):
  some.a = 20

ir = IntRef(10)
modify(ir)
print(ir)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not with an int as everyone has described. The "nicest" way depends on your goal but I just use a numpy array.

```
def modify(a):
    a += 10

x = np.array(10)
modify(x)
print(int(x))
```