# Dataframe column becomes entirely Nan even though no changes made

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on the classical titanic dataset in  kaggle and there are four dataframes in my project the test and training set and their copys to perform some operations on them. So my problem is even though I make the same operations on my test and train datasets my test datasets "Cabin" column becomes Nan. I couldn't understand the problem.

Code block 1:

```
training=pd.read_csv("../input/titanic/train.csv")
copytrain = training
training=training.drop(columns=["Ticket","PassengerId"])

test=pd.read_csv("../input/titanic/test.csv")
test=test.drop(columns=["Ticket","PassengerId"])
copytest=test
```

Code block 2:

```
for i in range(len(training["Cabin"])):
    if "A" in str(training.loc[i,"Cabin"]):
        training.loc[i,"Cabin"] = "A"
    if "B" in str(training.loc[i,"Cabin"]):
        training.loc[i,"Cabin"] = "B"
    if "C" in str(training.loc[i,"Cabin"]):
        training.loc[i,"Cabin"] = "C"
    if "D" in str(training.loc[i,"Cabin"]):
        training.loc[i,"Cabin"] = "D"
    if "E" in str(training.loc[i,"Cabin"]):
        training.loc[i,"Cabin"] = "E"
    if "F" in str(training.loc[i,"Cabin"]):
        training.loc[i,"Cabin"] = "F"
    if "G" in str(training.loc[i,"Cabin"]):
        training.loc[i,"Cabin"] = "G"
    
for i in range(len(test["Cabin"])):
    if "A" in str(test.loc[i,"Cabin"]):
        test.loc[i,"Cabin"] = "A"
    if "B" in str(test.loc[i,"Cabin"]):
        test.loc[i,"Cabin"] = "B"
    if "C" in str(test.loc[i,"Cabin"]):
        test.loc[i,"Cabin"] = "C"
    if "D" in str(test.loc[i,"Cabin"]):
        test.loc[i,"Cabin"] = "D"
    if "E" in str(test.loc[i,"Cabin"]):
        test.loc[i,"Cabin"] = "E"
    if "F" in str(test.loc[i,"Cabin"]):
        test.loc[i,"Cabin"] = "F"
    if "G" in str(test.loc[i,"Cabin"]):
        test.loc[i,"Cabin"] = "G"

training.loc[training["Cabin"]=="T","Cabin"]="A"
copytrain.loc[copytrain["Cabin"]=="T","Cabin"]="A"

        
test.loc[test["Cabin"]=="T","Cabin"]="A"
copytest.loc[test["Cabin"]=="T","Cabin"]="A"


training.loc[training.Cabin.isnull(),"Cabin"]="U"
test.loc[test.Cabin.isnull(),"Cabin"]="U"

test.Cabin.value_counts()
```

output:

```
U    327
C     35
B     18
D     13
E     11
A      7
F      6
G      1
Name: Cabin, dtype: int64
```

Code block 3:

```
copytrain["Cabin"]= copytrain["Cabin"].str.replace("A","")
copytrain["Cabin"]= copytrain["Cabin"].str.replace("B","")
copytrain["Cabin"]= copytrain["Cabin"].str.replace("C","")
copytrain["Cabin"]= copytrain["Cabin"].str.replace("D","")
copytrain["Cabin"]= copytrain["Cabin"].str.replace("E","")
copytrain["Cabin"]= copytrain["Cabin"].str.replace("F","")
copytrain["Cabin"]= copytrain["Cabin"].str.replace("G","")
#-------------------------------------------------------
copytest["Cabin"]= copytest["Cabin"].str.replace("A","")
copytest["Cabin"]= copytest["Cabin"].str.replace("B","")
copytest["Cabin"]= copytest["Cabin"].str.replace("C","")
copytest["Cabin"]= copytest["Cabin"].str.replace("D","")
copytest["Cabin"]= copytest["Cabin"].str.replace("E","")
copytest["Cabin"]= copytest["Cabin"].str.replace("F","")
copytest["Cabin"]= copytest["Cabin"].str.replace("G","")

copytrain.loc[(copytrain["Cabin"].str.len()==5) | (copytrain["Cabin"].str.len()==8),"Cabin"]=copytrain.Cabin.str.slice(stop=2)
copytrain.loc[(copytrain["Cabin"].str.len()==7) | (copytrain["Cabin"].str.len()==11),"Cabin"]=copytrain.Cabin.str.slice(stop=3)
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
copytest.loc[(copytest["Cabin"].str.len()==5) | (copytest["Cabin"].str.len()==8),"Cabin"]=copytest.Cabin.str.slice(stop=2)
copytest.loc[(copytest["Cabin"].str.len()==7) | (copytest["Cabin"].str.len()==11),"Cabin"]=copytest.Cabin.str.slice(stop=3)

copytrain["Cabin"]=pd.to_numeric(copytrain["Cabin"],errors="coerce")
copytest["Cabin"]=pd.to_numeric(copytest["Cabin"],errors="coerce")

test.Cabin.value_counts()
```

output:

```
Series([], Name: Cabin, dtype: int64)
```

Here are the first five rows of the training and test dataframes:

```
Surv    Pclass  Sex Age SibSp   Parch   Fare    Cabin   Embarked
0   3   male    22.0    1   0   7.2500  U   S
1   1   female  38.0    1   0   71.2833 C   C
1   3   female  26.0    0   0   7.9250  U   S
1   1   female  35.0    1   0   53.1000 C   S
0   3   male    35.0    0   0   8.0500  U   S`
```

```
Pclass  Sex Age SibSp   Parch   Fare    Cabin   Embarked
3   male    34.5    0   0   7.8292  U   Q
3   female  47.0    1   0   7.0000  U   S
2   male    62.0    0   0   9.6875  U   Q
3   male    27.0    0   0   8.6625  U   S
3   female  22.0    1   1   12.2875 U   S
```

Sometimes in jupyter the code is really buggy but this time I tried deleting the blocks and it didn't work.

Comment: Can you please describe, what you code is supposed to do? You code is by far to complicated. As a general hit, try to simlify. As fas as I can tell, you are replacing and counting values in the column `cabin`. Sometimes it looks like you are replacing any letter with an empty string. Plese give you question more focus.

Comment: So what I am trying to do in block 2 is changing the string values in the cabin part in to single  characters because they consist of both numbers and characters for example B253. I do it both for the training and test set. In the third block what I'm trying to do is seperate the numbers and characters that's why I replace them with an empty string in the copy of training and test set. The problem is after code block 3 even though I don't touch the test dataframe and in code block 2 it is in the format that I want it suddenly changes and I couldn't see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you question there are multiple topics, which are important and I want to go through it step by step.

### Pointer

It is important to understand what [pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106689/pointers-in-python) in python are.

Here is a small example, where the list in variable `a` is assinged to b. If you change `a`, `b` changes, too.

```
a = [0,1]
b = a # this is not a copy, this is a pointer to a
a[0] = 3 # if you modify a, b is also modified
print(b)
>>> [3,1]
```

You can try it on you console.

To make a copy in python you can use the package [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) using like below:

```
import copy
a = [0,1]
b = copy.copy(a) # this is a copy
a[0] = 3 # if you modify a, b is not modified
print(b)
>>> [0,1]
```

I guess in your code you have a pointer and not a copy. By the way, pandas has it's own copy, using like [`df.copy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) to make a copy of a DataFrame.

### Pandas vectorization

To make code readable, use the power of pandas. Write less code and mostly this is even faster.

With the [`replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) method of pandas you can go through the column and perform the task on each entry.

Below the Column `cabin` is used twice. First all digits (using `\d`) are replaced with an empty string, then all non digit (using `\D`) are replaced. Both times the result is added to the DataFrame in a new column.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Cabin':['A132', 'B221', 'C223', 'FF11']})
df['Cabin Letter'] = df['Cabin'].replace(r'\d', '', regex=True)
df['Cabin Number'] = df['Cabin'].replace(r'\D', '', regex=True)
```